Stackoverflow, retroactively increased reputation for answers, with a fair rational behind it
Shall discuss merits and problems of implementing such a change in quant.finance?


I thought about adding an answer to this but found I am actually ambivalent, or worse, apathetic towards this. Perhaps I just don't believe it will have any kind of impact.
